Parameterize bigquery table in Jupyter Notebook
I wrote a prophet model in workbench Vertex AI (interacting with bq tables)
Here is an example/the structure of my code:
Cell#1
DECLARE VAR_FIRST_MONTH_FIRST_DAY DATE;
DECLARE VAR_FIRST_MONTH_LAST_DAY DATE;
DECLARE VAR_BUSINESS_UNIT STRING;
...

SET VAR_FIRST_MONTH_FIRST_DAY = '2024-05-01'
SET VAR_FIRST_MONTH_LAST_DAY = '2024-05-31'
...
SET VAR_BUSINESS_UNIT = 'AAA'

create or replace table <table_1> as
SELECT
   <logic>
FROM <table_2>
;

create or replace table <table_3> as
SELECT
   <logic>
FROM <table_4>
LEFT JOIN <table_5>
;

Cell#2
client = bigquery.Client()
sql = "SELECT * from <table_1>"
data = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()

Cell#3
client = bigquery.Client()
sql = "SELECT * from <table_3>"
data = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()

Cell#4
export_to_bq(df=outliers, bq_table=<table_6>)

Is it possible to parameterize all table names in one cell and call them during the runtime?(wherever the are used)
